# Why there is no warning while casting from object to unbounded wildcard collection?

Tags: java, generics

Why is there no warning for the below code?

```
public void some(Object a){
    Map<?, ?> map = **(Map<?,?>)a**;  //converting unknown object to map    
}
```

I expected the RHS to have an unchecked warning.

While this code has a warning:

```
public void some(Object a){
   Map<Object, Object> map = **(Map<Object,Object>)a**;
  //converting unknown object to Map<Object,Object>      
}
```

Also, for below case there is no warning:

```
String str = (String) request.getAttribute("asd") //returns Object
```

Does this mean that unchecked warnings came with generics? There were no such warnings before introduction of generics in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get no "unchecked" warning because the cast is completely "checked" -- a cast to `Map<?,?>` only needs to ensure that the object is a `Map` (and nothing else), and that is completely checkable at runtime. In other words, `Map<?,?>` is a reifiable type.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the unchecked warning is only relevant to generic types.

What it means is: this cast from Object to `Map<T1, T2>` might succeed because the object is indeed a Map, but the runtime has no way, due to type erasure, to check that it's a `Map<T1, T2>`. It might very well be a `Map<T3, T4>`. So you might very well break the type-safety of the map by putting T1, T2 elements inside, or get a ClassCastException when trying to read values from the map.

You have no warning for the first cast because you're casting to a `Map<?, ?>`, which means that the key and the value type is unknown, which is true. You won't be able to perform a type-unsafe operation on such a map without additional casts: you can't add anything to such a map, and the only thing you can get out of it is instances of `Object`.

Comment: I could be wrong but wouldn't the cast from `Map<T1, T2>` to `Map<T3, T4>` result in a `ClassCastException`? You wouldn't really be able to add anything to the `Map` because the program will crash.

Comment: @ChetanKinger no, and that's why you get a warning. Due to type erasure, the runtime can check that the object is a Map, but it can't tell the generic type of the Map.

Comment: No, this wouldn't result in a ClassCastException. At Runtime, the JVM doesn't know what types the type parameters were bound to, so the JVM has no way to check if your cast to Map<Integer,String> is valid or not - you can easily cast a Map<String,OutputStream> to it because the JVM can't tell the difference.